# Returning A Variable From Outside Class

Tags: php, zend-framework, variables, return

I know this is probably the stupidest questions i've asked to date... but I keep looking for reference points and theres so many random questions that its most difficult to find.
I know its most likely an issue with the correct syntax, but for the life of me, and after much trial and error, I know its probably just easier to ask.... (also, lastInsertId() will not be a possible solution because there is other omitted code)... Does it have to be a global variable to return correctly... as far as my understanding.... not explicitly

Question:  How can I echo this variable correctly:

#### Echo Code

```
$customer = new SoClassy();
$var1 = "test 1";
$var2= "test 2";
$var3= "test 3";
try {
$customer->add_function($var1,$var2,$var3);
$last_insert_id= $customer->$return_this_variable; 

echo "HERE:  ";
echo $last_insert_id;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
print "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

#### Class Code (different *.php)

```
 function add_function($var1,$var2,$var3)
     {
        $data = array(
            'position_one' => $var1,
            'position_two' => $var2,
            'position_three' => $var3
        );
        try {
            $this->db->insert($this->config->database->tables->table_name, $data);
            $return_this_variable = $this->db->lastInsertId();
       return $return_this_variable;
            }
        catch ...{}
        catch ...{}
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your question. What do you need to return? At any case, you can make available to your function whatever you either return from a method/function or something which is already visible from outher scope (IE a global). Former is most always a wiser choice, because it reduces dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly.. the function is returning the value you want.  So you assign the function call to your variable:

`$last_insert_id = $customer->add_function($var1,$var2,$var3);`

Comment: but unfortunately, I cant use that specifically *because of omitted code, it runs multiple inserts below that excerpt*

Comment: okay well your function makes a query and gets the `lastInsertID()` and puts it in `$return_this_variable` and then returns that value.. so assuming your query stuff is right, that is what you are getting in `$last_insert_id`

Comment: the function itself works perfectly.... if I use your modified `$last_insert_id = ...` then I can use that to set the variable?

Comment: last tidbit of info I need...if I use that to actually set the variable, then it would essentially run the function twice, so I can get rid of the `$customer->function...` line right above it, correct?

Comment: no, you don't run it twice. you just run it once, in the code i showed.

Comment: so instead of `$customer->add_function($var1,$var2,$var3);
$last_insert_id= $customer->$return_this_variable; ` you just do the single line i posted

Answer (score 1):

Consider following an alternate approach to the one suggested to you, in the case you need to pass out something else than just one function result.

```
class SoClassy {

protected $itemId;

public function add_function($var1,$var2,$var3)
     {
        $data = array(
            'position_one' => $var1,
            'position_two' => $var2,
            'position_three' => $var3
        );
        try {
            $this->db->insert($this->config->database->tables->table_name, $data);
            $this->itemId = $this->db->lastInsertId();
            }
        catch ...{}
        catch ...{}
    }

}


public function doSomethingElse() {  ... }

public function doItAll($var1,$var2,$var3) {
    $this->add_function($var1,$var2,$var3)
    $this->doSomethingElse();
    return $this->itemId;
}

}
```

You might want to resort to something like this if you need to perform a lot of operations in your method, in order to avoid it becoming a monster one.

You can do whatever you want to itemId (or other class variables) in doSomethingElse and all other class methods. Basically you keep all temporary variables you need in one place, without making them global, risking for name clashes.

Comment: its a pretty crazy program and i'm just extending functionality at this point, so point taken, but i'm not gonna fully redesign the wheel... if ya catch my drift.  +1 for the suggestion though!

Comment: glad this can be useful to you. If you're going down heavy on db, I suggest that you take a look at stuff like Doctrine ORM. Takes care of handling much of the relational<->object oriented conversion hassle for you. Good luck!